# How to get the value of a class member variable from its name as a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there anyway to do this? Its like i have a class

```
public class TestClass
{
   public static string myString= "123";
}
```

I want to some how get the value 123 from myString. If i know the name myString and put it into a textbox1 then annother textbox2 shows me the value 123.

Tried something like this:

`var textForUrl = TestClass.GetType().GetField(txtbox1.Text).GetValue(TestClass, null)`

But not working, also, my variables are all located in a seperate .cs file.

Comment: "But not working" doesn't tell us *anything* about what happens. Please provide a [mcve] - ideally a console app. (It's not obvious why you're trying to pass two arguments to `GetValue`, for a start.) I'd also consider whether you *really* need to do this, instead of having a `Dictionary<string, string>` somewhere.

Comment: typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(nameof(myString)).GetValue(null) as string

Comment: Tried something and not working ? I didn't get what is your expectation.

Comment: You can take a look at reflection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get **field** `public static string myString = "123";`

```
var textForUrl = typeof(TestClass).GetField("myString")?.GetValue(null);
```

To get **property** `public static string { get; set; } myString = "123";`

```
var textForUrl = typeof(TestClass).GetProperty("myString")?.GetValue(null);
```